# Preservation of a scalar along geodesic trajectory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields, geodesics

Let $u^\mu$ be the velocity of a particle , and $\xi^\mu$ be a killing vector. would taking a contravariant derivative of to scalar product $\xi_\mu u^\mu$ , and showing that it equals to 0 shows that this scalar is preserved ?

Comment: That a quantity $\phi$ is conserved on a geodesic implies $u^\mu \nabla_\mu \phi = 0$. By the way, it is not $\xi_\mu u^\mu$ that is conserved on a geodesic, its $\xi_\mu p^\mu$

Comment: @Prahar , Please note that $\xi^\mu $ is a *Killing Vector*.

Comment: I did note that. Did I say something wrong?

Comment: my bad. so you're saying that under the mentioned conditions - $u^\mu\nabla_\mu(\xi_\nu u^\nu)=0$? (and I assume that $\nabla_\mu$ is the *contravariant* derivative? @Prahar

Comment: $\nabla_\mu$ is called the *covariant derivative*. Also to be clear again, the statement is $u^\mu \nabla_\mu \left( \xi_\nu p^\nu \right) = 0$. By the way, $\xi_\mu p^\mu$ is a scalar, so the above statement is equivalent to $p^\mu \partial_\mu \left( \xi^\nu p_\nu \right) = 0$. Also, just in case there is any confusion, I raise and lower indices freely using the metric. Further, I am stressing that its $p^\mu$ instead of $u^\mu$ because while $p^\mu$ is well defined for both massive and massless particles $u^\mu$ is only defined for massive particles.